# Is there any way to assign automatic value to sharepoint list column in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to assign value during adding or modifying items in SharePoint list. The value will be held in a session variable and assigned to a list column. It should be assigned automatically during adding new item. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure! Use jQuery and add the value when the URL points to edit and no other value is present.

Comment: I agree with Benny. This jquery needs to be added on the edit form page of the list. This is a very simple, quick solution.